# Implicitly redirect in Apache

Tags: apache

I have Apache and want to implicitly redirect http request to a file.

That is, when a user hits http://example.com/foo/bar, I wish a user to see a content on .xml file under /some/folder/file.xml and at the same time a user must see http://example.com/foo/bar in the address bar.

Redirect instruction in httpd.conf makes a URL being changed once it gets redirected, but I want to keep the URL same.

Comment: You do not want  a "redirection", but an internal "rewriting". See the documentation for `RewriteRule`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "/foo/bar$"  "/some/folder/file.xml" [PT]
```

you can even specify mime-type.

```
RewriteRule    "/foo/bar$"  "/some/folder/file.xml" [PT,H=application/xml]
```

You need internal remapping.

Comment: No as `$` ends the url as closure and it should be exactly matching the url. If you want with keywords you can chnge it to `/foo/bar*$`